# Creating a calendar in Second Route widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am *very* new to using Flutter and can't figure out how to include a calendar on a widget I am using as the 'second route'.

```
class FirstRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstRoute({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _FirstRoute createState() => _FirstRoute();
}

class _FirstRoute extends State<FirstRoute> {
  CalendarController _controller;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Project'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar(calendarController: _controller,)
          ...
```

Currently, this works to show the calendar on the first page but I am wanting it on the second page which I have as:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
          ...
```

And navigate to using:

```
          ...
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Calendar'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                     context, 
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute())
                );
              },
            ),
          ...
```

Is there a way of using the `TableCalendar(calendarController: _controller,)` in the second route? I tried to add of the calendar code into the second route but this does not work as you can't use the `initState()` in a widget. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to maintain a state that goes beyond one widget, like your `CalendarController`, consider to handle the state outside the widget. Take look on [this overview](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and the [official docs about state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) to find out more about alternatives to local state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you want to use initState in the SecondRoute page, it must extend StatefulWidget as following

```
class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
     _SecondRoute createState() => _SecondRoute();
}

class _SecondRoute extends State<SecondRoute> {
  CalendarController _controller;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Second Route"), ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
            TableCalendar(calendarController: _controller,)
        ],
      ),
   ),
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!